How can I modify a variable / argument passed to a script online/inline
I'm looking for passing a variable to script (I know how to do that), that will be echoed by the script in order to slightly modify that variable.
$ [scriptname] foo bar 

where [scriptname] is the name of the program, and foo and bar the two arguments passed.
[Edited for clarification, after comment:] The resulting file should be named foo_bar1, but with the option for the user to make minor modifications to this file name that one can't know beforehand.
Therefore it could look like
$ [scriptname] foo bar
The output file name will be foo_bar1

And here I wished I could interactively use, like backslash, remove the 1 and replace it by underscore (_) and 2:
The output file name will therefore be foo_bar_2
And this would subsequently be a known or new variable in the script, so that the results of this script can be written into an output file called foo_bar_2. Reason for my question is, that the file names are not just 3 chars, but rather long, and contain specific data. So the user ought not (try to) re-type dozens of characters; often the output file name will be the one as proposed. The user will see it, most often just 'Enter'. Though also have the chance to add own, minor, modifications. [I hope this explains somewhat better what I need.?]
Is this possible? If yes, I'd gladly learn how to do that.
And it isn't necessarily only the last number (I'd know how to remove/isolate it). But at times, I ought to be able to also call the output foofoo_bar_2.

Your question is still rather difficult to understand. Are you saying that your script outputs an editable suggested filename (using something like the GNU readline library - as with the bash shell read command's -e option), but instead of editing the proposed filename interactively you wish to edit it programmatically?

I agree it's hard to understand exactly what you'd like to accomplish, I believe it would be best for you to just post an example of all the possible "filenames" you wish to generate, in a way that makes it clear what can change and what not.

Based on my understanding of what you are trying to do, I have written a bash script. It takes two arguments. The script will exit if exactly two arguments are not provided. If the script finds two arguments it will combine them with an _ in between and a 1 as the suffix to form a "filename". Then the script will present this "filename" to the user and the user will have an opportunity to edit it as they please.
The script:
Create a file called altname with the following contents:
#!/bin/bash
# Purpose: This script takes two arguments and creates a filename with it.
#      Then it presents the user with the filename and an oppotunity to alter it.

# Check for two arguments
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "Usage: $0 arg1 arg2"
  exit 3
fi

# Create the proposed filename by adding "_" and "1"
filename="$1"_"$2"1

# Ask the user for approval or change
echo "This is the proposed filename."
read -e -i "$filename" -p "Hit Enter to accept or change:" filename
echo "the final filename is: $filename"  

Save the file. Open a terminal and run the script with the command:
./altname foo bar

This is the proposed filename.
Hit Enter to accept or change:foo_bar1

You should see a prompt like above. Use the arrow keys, delete, backspace, etc. to alter the name and hit Enter. The script will then display the final filename.
Hope this helps

Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!
